# Why are elliptic curves over a field of characteristic 2 or 3 insecure?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, finite-field

The following is a quotation from my cryptography course:

> Recent results on the discrete logarithm raise big concerns on the security of elliptic curves over a binary field.

What are these results? Also, is characteristic three safe?

Comment: Related [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8479/555).

Comment: @fgrieu That certainly addresses the first question, thanks. What about characteristic 3?

Comment: This is flying quite above my head, but my understanding is that the Joux results apply to some level for small characteristics larger than two. Try [his bibliography on Discrete Logarithms](https://www-almasty.lip6.fr/~joux/pages/DiscLogarithms.html).

Comment: Not a full answer, but here's an attack on characteristic three curves [involving Weil descent](http://lab.iisec.ac.jp/~arita/pdf/acrypFinal.pdf).

Comment: The usual reason to distrust low-characteristic elliptic curve groups is the [Petit-Quisquater result](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/146), which suggests the discrete logarithm might be subexponential there. But as far as I know, the real-world relevance of this result is still in question.

Comment: Note that there is a lot of space between "insecure" in the title and "big concerns" in the quote. "big concerns" could already have been exaggerated somewhat and "insecure" would then apply even less.

Comment: At least in the case of pairing-based cryptography, the pairing-friendly curves in small characteristic are broken because of Joux result combined with the [MOV attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/how-does-the-mov-attack-work), since those curves were all supersingular ones.

Comment: @Charles Those are a different kind of discrete logarithms, they do not concern elliptic curve discrete logarithms except in some rare specialized cases, e.g., low embedding degree.

Comment: @SamuelNeves You're right, how careless of me. I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *known* subexponential-cost algorithm for computing discrete logs in elliptic curves over fields of small characteristic—barring standard generic algorithms on groups of smooth order, transfers to $\operatorname{GF}(2^n)$, *etc.*—but there *seems* to be exploitable structure that just hasn't been worked out yet.  The most recent survey seems to be from 2015:

> [Stephen D. Galbraith and Pierrick Gaudry, ‘Recent progress on the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem’, IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive: Report 2015/1022, 2015-10-22.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1022)

See in particular [§10.2, ‘A subexponential algorithm for elliptic curves over $\mathbb F_{2^n}$?’, p. 18](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1022.pdf#page=18).

Comment: Pierrick Gaudry, not Patrick. ;)